# How can we conclude that the given number will come in a pythagorean triplet?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can we conclude that the given number can form a pythagorean triplate or not? Can we find that triplet?  For example the given number is 3. 3,4,5 is a pythagorean triplate which includes 3. So our answer for the number three is 3,4,5 & triplet is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any odd number $2n+1$ is part of the triplet $2n+1,2n^2+2n,2n^2+2n+1$. If $m$ is even, and not a power of 2, then $m=2^k(2n+1)$ for some $k$ and $n$, and $m$ is a part of $m,2^k(2n^2+2n),2^k(2n^2+2n+1)$. And if $n$ is a power of $2$, then it's part of $3s,4s,5s$ for appropriate $s$. The only exceptions are $n=1$ and $n=2$.

Comment: Ohh then I have got the solution of that question on which we were talking. Very interesting but long solution!!Thanks.... Again sorry for my bad words.:(

Comment: I hope you will post your solution to the other problem.

Comment: One more question.... For any given number, Can we find ALL Pythagoras triplate  which includes that number?

Comment: Sure. Every triple is of the form $$2kmn,(m^2-n^2)k,(m^2+n^2)k$$ for some positive integers $m,n,k$ with $m>n$ and with $m$ and $n$ relatively prime and of opposite parity. So to find all the triples including $N$, all you have to do is find all the solutions to $N=2kmn$, $N=(m^2-n^2)k$, and $N=(m^2+n^2)k$.

Comment: Still waiting for your solution to the other problem.